# Objects with the same var values seems to be the one object for index() method in List

Tags: python

So I have a model Card. In project I create the cardData wrapper of this model:

```
card = Card.objects.get(id=someId)
cardData = {}
cardData.id = card.id
cardData.title = card.title
```

Than I put over 30 cardDatas in deck list:

```
deck = [cardData1, cardData2 ..., cardData17]
```

Finally somewhere in game I have a link for example on cardCata17. Which contains in deck list. But at the same time there is also cardData2 whith the same params becouse it is also was created from the same model. And when I try to get index of cardData17:

```
index = deck.index(cardData17)
```

It return index = 2, and not 17 because the cardData two also has same id and title. That is rather strange and I spend a lot of time to understand this problem. Is it real or I mistake in this assumption.

Comment: The identity has nothing to do with what you are looking for, if you have two dicts with the same content then the first match will be returned.

Comment: The objects are different. There are both have the same values if id, but the litterals were different. So the strange is that this is two different objects, but both contains in one list, and both have the same values of id and tittle.

Comment: Are they dicts or objects?

Comment: As you can see they are objects: cardData = {}

Comment: that is a dictionary, can you add you actual code because dicts don't have id or title attributes

Comment: Ok, sorry my knowledge of python leaves much to be desired. But even if it dictionary and I have two dictionaries in list with the same content why it gives me the indexfirst one and not the index of link dictionary?!

Comment: Padraic is right. You need to make an object for the card data instead of a dictionary if you want them to be unique instances. Dictionaries ({}) will be the same if their contents are the same.

Comment: I afraid the real code is two big forr this post. But the main idea is the same. I create a litteral {id:card.id, title:card.title} put several litteral in list and whe I try to find index of some litterals sometimes it gives me a wrong because the index method found another litterals which has the smae content.

Comment: If I put one more variable in this dictionary for example rand int uid is it solve my problem?!

Comment: If you have two dicts in a list d1 and d2 and both dicts have the exact same contents no matter what dict you look for you will always get the findex of the first occurrence.  It is exactly that same as `l = [1,2,3,3].index(3)`

Comment: Thank you Padraic. I understand the problem. In future I refactor this and change dictionaries on objects. The random uids for this dictionaries was quick solution of this problem! Glad you help me with this!

Comment: Putting a random unique int will solve your problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Make objects of card data instead of dictionaries. The objects will be identified by their memory location, which is unique, instead of by their content.

```
class CardData(object):
  def __init__(self, id, title):
    self.id = id
    self.title = title

card = Card.objects.get(id=someId)
cardData = CardData(card.id, card.title)
```